Get TenantSpecificOidcIdentityProvider programmatically
I need to authenticate with an access-token (and, if needed, a refresh-token). I get this token from a Kafka-record, so I have no HTTP-context.
To do this, using TenantIdentityProvider seemed to be a good idea, because this is the only way I found for which no RoutingContext is needed. These providers are injectable and by using @Tenant, also a tenant-specific provider is available.
Is there a way to get a TenantIdentityProvider for a tenant programatically, i.e. by giving the tenant-id and getting the provider? Because I need to support multiple tenants and the idea is to get the tenant-id by selecting the OIDC-config for the issuer of the token (which already works).
I tried to get it by using a CDI-instance, but @Tenant is no qualifier and only the default provider seems to be available as CDI-bean, I suppose the rest are synthetic beans.
For now I'm using OidcRecorder.createTenantIdentityProvider in my code, which is obviously not the best choice. But IMHO this is the only way, because TenantSpecificOidcIdentityProvider is a private class and therefore no instantiable for me.
Please let me know if there is a better way. Thanks in advance.
